# evercookie (call method of object)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, cookies

//this code is in script.js file

```
 var E_c = (function () {

var etagCookieName = 'ecn';
var cacheCookieName = 'ccn';

  this._class = function () {

    this.set = function (name, value) {
        alert(name);
        alert(value);
    }
}; 
return this._class;});
```

in another file i have create object of E_c but if i try to call set method using ec.set() it generate error that  ec.set() is not a function.please guide where i am went wrong . here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function create_cookie() {

        var ec = new E_c();
         ec.set("id","567")  ;   

    }

        create_cookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var E_c = (function () {

var etagCookieName = 'ecn';
var cacheCookieName = 'ccn';

  this._class = function () {

    this.set = function (name, value) {
        alert(name);
        alert(value);
    }
}; 
return this._class;}()); // <-- () to execute the anonymous functions
```

Comment: Hi @MuhammadTariq if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.